# Vue: Update part of an html string from data v-for loop with v-model input

Tags: vue.js, for-loop, vue-reactivity

Using Vue2 I have an array of objects in data which have an html string rendered in a v-for loop.  Part of each string is a prop, which renders correctly initially.  However, when the prop value is updated with v-model the data in the v-for loop is not updated.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jumki/9os47vtj/12/): When the input is changed from "Bob" to "Sally" all instances should change, but those in the for-loop do not.

**html**

```html
<div id="app">
  <h2>Testing</h2>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="statement in statements" v-html="statement.text"></li>
  </ul>
  
  <input v-model="name" placeholder="edit name">
  <p>Name is: {{ name }}</p>
  
  <p class="italic">Outside loop: <b>{{name}}</b> likes dogs.</p>
</div>
```

**vue**

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: function() {
    return {
      statements: [
          {
            id: 'food',
            text: '<b>'+ this.name + '</b> likes to eat ice cream.',
          },
          {
            id: 'fun',
            text: 'Running is the favorite activity of <b>'+ this.name + '</b>',
          },
      ],
    }
  },
  
  props: { 
    name: {
      type: String,
      default: 'Bob',
    },
  },
})
```

The code has been simplified - the actual HTML strings have ~3 variables each that need to update, and are at different locations in each string, so I can't think of another way to replace the values when they are updated, while preserving the html tags.  This is intended to be a single-page vue application, but is using Laravel and blade for some general page formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `name` should be in `data`, not in `props` (it's not coming from a parent, it's just reactive data, which needs to be tracked for changes internally - inside this component).
2. `statements` should be in `computed`, because you want Vue to update it whenever its reactive references (e.g: `this.name`) change. Besides, `this` is not what you think it is inside the `data` function.

See it working:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: () => ({
    name: 'Bob'
  }),
  computed: {
    statements() {
        return [
        {
          id: 'food',
          text: '<b>'+ this.name + '</b> likes to eat ice cream.',
        },
        {
          id: 'fun',
          text: 'Runing is the favorite activity of <b>'+ this.name + '</b>',
        },
      ]
    }
  },
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
}

li {
  margin: 8px 0;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

p.italic {
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://v2.vuejs.org/js/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h2>Testing</h2>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="(statement, key) in statements" v-html="statement.text" :key="key"></li>
  </ul>
  
  <input v-model="name" placeholder="edit name">
  <p>Name is: {{ name }}</p>
  
  <p class="italic">Outside loop: <b>{{name}}</b> likes dogs.</p>
</div>
```

---

If you're trying to create a reusable component which takes in a person (with some values) and creates the statements based on those values ***and also allows editing*** the person's values, here's how to do it:

```js
Vue.component('person-editor', {
  template: '#person-editor-tpl',
  props: {
    person: {
      type: Object,
      default: () => ({})
    }
  },
  data: () => ({
    details: [
      { name: 'name', placeholder: 'Name' },
      { name: 'fun', placeholder: 'Running', label: 'Favorite activity' },
      { name: 'food', placeholder: 'pizza', label: 'Favorite food'}
    ]
  }),
  methods: {
    update(payload) {
      this.$emit('update:person', { ...this.person, ...payload })
    },
    getDetailLabel(d) {
      return d.label || (d.name[0].toUpperCase() + d.name.slice(1))
    }
  }
});

Vue.component('person-details', {
  template: '#person-details-tpl',
  props: {
    person: {
      type: Object,
      default: () => ({})
    }
  },
  data: () => ({
    statements: [
      { id: 'food', text: p => `<b>${p.name}</b> likes to eat ${p.food}.` },
      { id: 'fun', text: p => `${p.fun} is the favorite activity of <b>${p.name}</b>` }
    ]
  })
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: () => ({
    persons: [
      { name: 'Jane', food: 'apples', fun: 'Hiking' },
      { name: 'Jack', food: 'pizza', fun: 'Sleeping' }
    ]
  }),
  methods: {
    updatePerson(key, value) {
      this.persons.splice(key, 1, value);
    }
  }
})
```

```css
label {
  display: flex;
}
label > span {
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://v2.vuejs.org/js/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <template v-for="(person, key) in persons">
    <hr v-if="key" :key="`hr-${key}`">
    <person-details :person="person"
                    :key="`details-${key}`"
                    ></person-details>
    <person-editor :person.sync="person"
                   :key="`editor-${key}`"
                   @update:person="updatePerson(key, person)"></person-editor>
  </template>
</div>

<template id="person-editor-tpl">
  <div>
    <template v-for="detail in details">
      <label :key="detail.name">
        <span v-text="getDetailLabel(detail)"></span>
        <input :value="person[detail.name]"
               @input="e => update({ [detail.name]: e.target.value })">
      </label>
    </template>
  </div>
</template>

<template id="person-details-tpl">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="(statement, key) in statements" v-html="statement.text(person)"></li>
  </ul>
</template>
```

I separated the editor and the display in two separate components.
Because I had to define the components on the Vue instance it's a bit crammed in this example, but it looks a lot more elegant when using sfcs (and each component is a standalone .vue file).

Comment: Thanks!  The first example is what I was looking for at the moment, but I appreciate the second example and think it will be a helpful reference in future. It felt wrong to have the data in computed, since the statements are static except for the variables, but it does work, and the statements do need to be recomputed with changes.  I've had to use "this." to reference props in data before, which is why I did it this time, but I'll try to dig into the implications to better understand what is happening.